# PHP eval and capturing errors (as much as possible)

Tags: php, exception, parsing, eval

***Disclaimer***; I'm fully aware of the pitfalls and "evils" of eval, including but not limited to: performance issues, security, portability etc.

**The problem**

Reading the PHP manual on eval...

> eval() returns NULL  unless return is
>   called in the evaluated code, in which
>   case the value passed to return is
>   returned. If there is a parse error in
>   the evaluated code, eval()  returns
>   FALSE and execution of the following
>   code continues normally. It is not
>   possible to catch a parse error in
>   eval()  using set_error_handler().

In short, no error capture except returning false which is very helpful, but I'm sur eI could do way better!

**The reason**

A part of the site's functionality I'm working on relies on executing expressions. I'd like not to pass through the path of sandbox or execution modules, so I've ended using eval. Before you shout "what if the client turned bad?!" know that the client is pretty much trusted; he wouldn't want to break his own site, and anyone getting access to this functionality pretty much owns the server, regardless of eval.

The client knows about expressions like in Excel, and it isn't a problem explaining the little differences, however, having some form of warning is pretty much standard functionality.

This is what I have so far:

```
define('CR',chr(13));
define('LF',chr(10));

function test($cond=''){
    $cond=trim($cond);
    if($cond=='')return 'Success (condition was empty).'; $result=false;
    $cond='$result = '.str_replace(array(CR,LF),' ',$cond).';';
    try {
        $success=eval($cond);
        if($success===false)return 'Error: could not run expression.';
        return 'Success (condition return '.($result?'true':'false').').';
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return 'Error: exception '.get_class($e).', '.$e->getMessage().'.';
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- The function returns a message string in any event
- The code expression should be a single-line piece of PHP, without PHP tags and without an ending semicolon
- New lines are converted to spaces
- A variable is added to contain the result (expression should return either true or false, and in order not to conflict with eval's return, a temp variable is used.)

So, what would you add to further aide the user? Is there any further parsing functions which might better pinpoint possible errors/issues?

Chris.

Comment: if you could provide more feedback on what "expressions" you will use, maybe we can help more. I could think of some nice token_get_all stuff to validate the user input ;)

Comment: Normal PHP code? I plan to allow full access to PHP, with the possible exception of defining functions and classes, which isn't needed.

Comment: @Sz. that being said, I'd recommend using [symfony/expression-language](https://github.com/symfony/expression-language) nowadays (it was not available back in '10).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found a good alternative/answer to my question.

First of, let me start by saying that nikic's suggestion works when I set error_reporting(E_ALL); notices are shown in PHP output, and thanks to OB, they can be captured.

Next, I've found this very useful code:

```
/**
 * Check the syntax of some PHP code.
 * @param string $code PHP code to check.
 * @return boolean|array If false, then check was successful, otherwise an array(message,line) of errors is returned.
 */
function php_syntax_error($code){
    if(!defined("CR"))
        define("CR","\r");
    if(!defined("LF"))
        define("LF","\n") ;
    if(!defined("CRLF"))
        define("CRLF","\r\n") ;
    $braces=0;
    $inString=0;
    foreach (token_get_all('<?php ' . $code) as $token) {
        if (is_array($token)) {
            switch ($token[0]) {
                case T_CURLY_OPEN:
                case T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES:
                case T_START_HEREDOC: ++$inString; break;
                case T_END_HEREDOC:   --$inString; break;
            }
        } else if ($inString & 1) {
            switch ($token) {
                case '`': case '\'':
                case '"': --$inString; break;
            }
        } else {
            switch ($token) {
                case '`': case '\'':
                case '"': ++$inString; break;
                case '{': ++$braces; break;
                case '}':
                    if ($inString) {
                        --$inString;
                    } else {
                        --$braces;
                        if ($braces < 0) break 2;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $inString = @ini_set('log_errors', false);
    $token = @ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ob_start();
    $code = substr($code, strlen('<?php '));
    $braces || $code = "if(0){{$code}\n}";
    if (eval($code) === false) {
        if ($braces) {
            $braces = PHP_INT_MAX;
        } else {
            false !== strpos($code,CR) && $code = strtr(str_replace(CRLF,LF,$code),CR,LF);
            $braces = substr_count($code,LF);
        }
        $code = ob_get_clean();
        $code = strip_tags($code);
        if (preg_match("'syntax error, (.+) in .+ on line (\d+)$'s", $code, $code)) {
            $code[2] = (int) $code[2];
            $code = $code[2] <= $braces
                ? array($code[1], $code[2])
                : array('unexpected $end' . substr($code[1], 14), $braces);
        } else $code = array('syntax error', 0);
    } else {
        ob_end_clean();
        $code = false;
    }
    @ini_set('display_errors', $token);
    @ini_set('log_errors', $inString);
    return $code;
}
```

Seems it easily does exactly what I need (yay)!

Comment: Wow, this looks nice. And again I've learned something new: `break` can have an argument! I will later cast a look at this code to really understand what it does.
Only one note: If there are heavy parse errors in the code, `token_get_all` can output errors by itself, e.g. if you are using `\\` in the source (in PHP <5.3).

Comment: It is very nice.  Sadly it still does not - can not - provide protection against wrong function calls, e.g. simple spelling mistakes in function names.

PHP should really think about catching fatal errors in eval().

Answer (score 32):

Since PHP 7 eval() will generate a [`ParseError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.parseerror.php) exception for syntax errors:

```
try {
    $result = eval($code);
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    // Report error somehow
}
```

In PHP 5 eval() will generate a parse error, which is special-cased to not abort execution (as parse errors would usually do). However, it also cannot be caught through an error handler. A possibility is to catch the printed error message, assuming that `display_errors=1`:

```
ob_start();
$result = eval($code);
if ('' !== $error = ob_get_clean()) {
    // Report error somehow
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did define them, sorry for not mentioning. Fixed above code. As to exceptions, I'm pretty sure it doesn't neither, however, this code might fail in the future after perhaps adding exceptions to it, so it doesn't hurt handling them anyway.

Comment: I was not able to find `check_syntax`.

Comment: `php_check_syntax` was removed in 5.0.5, they expect you to do something like `exec("echo '<?php $code' | /usr/local/bin/php -l  2>/dev/null", $out, $ret);`  which is _so_ much more convenient.

Comment: `!==` operator has higher precedence than `=`. You need to add parentheses: `('' !== ($error = ob_get_clean()))`

Comment: @François Not if the assignment is on the RHS. That's why a Yoda condition is used here.

Comment: @Sz. Good point, I've updated the answer to mention ParseError.

Comment: if you're using namespaces, remember the backslash in `catch (\ParseError)`!  I spent an hour trying to figure out why my script wasn't catching the error correctly... adding the backslash fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

How to test for parse errors inside eval():

```
$result = @eval($evalcode . "; return true;");
```

If `$result == false`, `$evalcode` has a parse error and does not execute the 'return true' part. Obviously `$evalcode` must not ***return*** itself something, but with this trick you can test for parse errors in expressions effectively...

Comment: Very intelligent idea! I haven't tested it yet but I will.

Comment: You can't catch Parse Errors in `eval`'d code! It would just stop execution of your script.

Comment: This worked great for me, even with my eval() returning a value.  I have `$value=eval("return ".$evalcode."; return false;");` and then `if ($value===false) echo ("Error with: ".$evalcode);`  Of course this means that evalcode can never return false in a normal circumstance.  But that fits my use.

Answer (score 4):

I think that best solution is

```php
try {
    eval(/* ... */);
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    //...
}
```

It catches every error and exception, including `Call to undefined function` etc

Comment: This doesn't seem to catch Parse Errors.

Answer (score 3):

**Good news:** [As of PHP 7](http://php.net/eval), `eval()` now* throws a `ParseError` exception if the evaluated code is invalid:

```
try
{
    eval("Oops :-o");
}
catch (ParseError $err)
{
    echo "YAY! ERROR CAPTURED: $err";
}
```

---

* *Well, for quite a while then... ;)*

Answer (score 2):

You can also try something like this:

```
$filePath = '/tmp/tmp_eval'.mt_rand();
file_put_contents($filePath, $evalCode);
register_shutdown_function('unlink', $filePath);
require($filePath);
```

So any errors in $evalCode will be handled by errors handler.