# Validate an Expression in PHP

Tags: php, expression

I have an `textbox`, for user input an expression. I want to validate the inputed expression. Is there any way to do this?
**For example :** (1 * 2) + 3 *4 is True, (1 ** 2) +* 3 is false.
Thanks so much.

Comment: What you have so far to achieve this ?

Comment: Is your intent to *evaluate* the expression once you've determined if it's valid? If so, you should just ask *that* question instead.

Comment: @meagar, I just want to validate expression, not intent to do anything else. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you're going to need to use `eval()`, unless you want to pull some shenanigans with `php_check_syntax()` which would require you to save the expression to a file, which seems unwieldy.

`eval()` will return `false` if there's a syntax error in the code; if not, it will return `null` or the return value of the supplied expression.  This will cause you some grief if you're evaluating an expression that returns false normally, though.

Note that using `eval()` will allow anyone to input arbitrary PHP into your form and have it executed, which can obviously be a Very Bad Idea and should be approached with extreme caution.

Check out this similar question: [PHP eval and capturing errors (as much as possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223899/php-eval-and-capturing-errors-as-much-as-possible)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of any help (your question is a bit vague*), but someone has a aritmethic evaluator (without `eval`!) available: [PHP function to evaluate string like "2-1" as arithmetic 2-1=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1)

Then perhaps assign the results as

```
$true = <(1 * 2) + 3 *4 result here>;
$false = <(1 ** 2) +* 3 result here>;
```

and use for validating.

If you need to just validate the strings, try regular expressions or exact string matching with spaces removed.

```
// Basic string matching.
$expected = '(1*2)+3*4';
$data = <get data from text input to this variable or similar>;

if ($expected == str_replace(' ', '', $data)) {
    return true;
}

...
```

If you need to validate the formatting (e.g. mathematical correctness of the given string), try the arithmetic evaluator to check whether the string returns a number:

```
$value = <use arithmetic evaluator to get the value>;

if (is_numeric($value)) {
    return true;
}

...
```

* Could you make it clearer what in those values should return `true` or `false`. Does it need to be calculated to a certain number value? Does the string need to be an exact match? Does the string change constantly and need to be validated as a proper mathematically correct expression?