# Replace eval() php in logical operations

Tags: php, laravel, eval

I'm doing a logic validation like

```
$answer = eval("return ".$stringToValidate.";");
```

where `$stringToValidate` is a logic expression like `'a' == 'b'` or `100 < 200`.

The problem is when I introduce a invalid string like `a == 'b'` or `100 <<< 200`.

I´m looking for a replacement for eval function or try-catch syntax error

I was trying using try catch like

```
try{
    $answer = eval("return ".$stringToValidate.";");
}catch(Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

but didn't work

i expect the output true and false of eval function and a exception control for syntax error

EDIT:

i tryed  the solutions of duplicated and have the same problem, using the try-catch or the function [PHP eval and capturing errors (as much as possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223899/php-eval-and-capturing-errors-as-much-as-possible)

specifically if use a expresion `10000 < 20000 < 30000` and get the textual error `syntax error, unexpected '<'`
i investigate the symfony expresion language tool https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html
but when the expresion fails here, throw `false` and i cannot diference a bad expresion and a expresion that was `false`

EDIT2: parse errors cannot be catched
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: `a == 'b'` generates a *warning*, not an exception, when I try it. `100 <<< 200` generates a parse error, which you can't catch.

Comment: A better duplicate: [PHP eval and capturing errors (as much as possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223899/php-eval-and-capturing-errors-as-much-as-possible) - TL;DR use PHP7 and catch `ParseError`.

Comment: @cmbuckley Cheers, I've added that to the dupes list.

Comment: Thanks, I've just noticed the link to do that myself in future ;-)

Comment: @ceejayoz exist any form of capturing that parse error?

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP 7, you can use ParserError :

error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
$stringToValidate = "'a == 'b'";

try {
    $answer = eval("return ".$stringToValidate.";");
} catch(Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage();
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    echo 'Bad request !';
}
```

*Edit : see cmbuckley comment*